# How to correctly update a ViewModel/Model in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm in a situation when I want to update some of my properties in my viewmodel, however other half of my properties will be getting `null` if I don't specified using `@Html.hiddenFor` in submit form.

some code to make it clear :

```
public class CountryViewModel(){

  //I have 6 Country properties based on continent
  public string countryEurope1{get; set;}
  public string countryEurope2{get; set;}
  public string countryEurope3{get; set;}

  public string countryAsia1 {get; set;}
  public string countryAsia2 {get; set;}
  public string countryAsia3 {get; set;}
}
```

and then I have a view to show the countries, on this view I have 2 action link to edit country based on its continent.

**ShowCountry.cshtml**

```
    //View to show all my countries
    @Html.DisplayFor(c => c.countryEurope1)
    @Html.DisplayFor(c => c.countryEurope2)
    @Html.DisplayFor(c => c.countryEurope3)

    @Html.DisplayFor(c => c.countryAsia1 )
    @Html.DisplayFor(c => c.countryAsia2 )
    @Html.DisplayFor(c => c.countryAsia3 )

    //action link going to edit europe country view
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit Europe", "EditEuropeCountry", Model, null);

    //action link going to edit europe country view
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit Asia", "EditAsiaCountry", Model, null);
```

My edit Europe view 
**EditEuropeView.cshtml**

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("submitEurope", "Setting", FormMethod.Post)) {

        //Here I have to use @Html.HiddenFor to preserve value
        @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.countryAsia1)
        @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.countryAsia2)
        @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.countryAsia3)

        @Html.EditorFor(c => c.countryEurope1)
        @Html.EditorFor(c => c.countryEurope2)
        @Html.EditorFor(c => c.countryEurope3)

        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
    }
```

As you can see in `EditEuropeView.cshtml` I have to specified `countryAsia` properties using `@Html.Hiddenfor`, if I don't do this the `countryAsia` value will be `null` when I submitting the form. and I think this practice is very uneffecient, imagine if I have hundred `countryAsia` properties? do I have to write `@Html.hiddenfor` hundred times?

Is there any much more efficient technique/practice to update some of your viewModel properties?

Comment: Try to be more specific when using ViewModel. What I mean maybe the better solution is to divide your ViewModel. Create a composite ViewModel for the view mode and use a separate ViewModel for the edit mode.

Comment: @dama could you give some example?

Comment: Yes its inefficient (and open to attacks by malicious users). Its a view model so only include the properties you need. You do not need the hidden inputs because when you post, you get the data model from  the repository based on the ID, and update only those properties you need from the view model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke so I have to assign manually data from viewModel to Model after I get the model from repository?

Comment: Yes, you would get the data model, update just its `countryEurope1` etc properties and finally save the data model.

Comment: but let's say if I updated `countryEurope1` to `countryErope10` properties from viewModel, I have to manually assign that ten properties from ViewModel to Model?